BluetoothChat for Classic Bluetooth sample is marked as deprecated. What use instead?
BluetoothChat for Classic Bluetooth sample is marked as deprecated.
https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/main/BluetoothChat

Warning This sample has been deprecated and is no longer being maintained. Find the new bluetooth samples in the new platform-samples repo.

There is no BluetoothChat for Classic Bluetooth sample in new repo.
https://github.com/android/platform-samples/tree/main/samples/connectivity/bluetooth
Where can I find up to date version of BluetoothChat sample?
P.S. Google Classic Bluetooth documentation is still referencing to BluetoothChat sample,
but the code is modified and improved. Want to find where improved/modified project is hosted.
E.g. BluetoothChatService.ConnectedThread.run() method
https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/main/BluetoothChat
   public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (mState == STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
   }

https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-data
   public void run() {
       mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
       int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()

       // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
       while (true) {
           try {
               // Read from the InputStream.
               numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
               // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
               Message readMsg = handler.obtainMessage(
                       MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1,
                       mmBuffer);
               readMsg.sendToTarget();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
               break;
           }
       }
   }

